# Making AngularJS, ReactJS, ngReact, Browserify, Reactify, Material-UI play well together

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I'm building a web application based on the frameworks specified in the title:

- AngularJS: MVP engine
- ReactJS: "V" component in MVP
- ngReact: to inject React components into the AngularJS application
- Browserify+Reactity: to define require() function used by material-UI which uses react-tap-event-plugin
- Material-UI: set of ReactJS components to add Material Design-themed components

My implementation strategy is as follows:

- structure an AngularJS (it's an existing application, it works)
- load ReactsJS and ngReact
- load Material-UI: it works >> I tried (within **js/directives.js**):

  ```
  console.log(mui);
  ```

and the output is:

```
    Object {AppBar: function, AppCanvas: function, Checkbox: function, DatePicker: function, Dialog: function…}
```

which is a set of Material Design components as expected.

**js/directives.js** file (included within **script** in index.html) is made of the following code:

```
/* define directives for ngReact's Material-Ui components */
angular.module('myapp.reactDirectives', [])
.directive('RaisedButton', function(reactDirective) {
    return reactDirective(mui.RaisedButton);
});
```

Now, everything looks fine but it looks like AngularJS is **ignoring** my **.directive** function call as when I use (in one of my views):

```
 <RaisedButton label="Primary" primary={true} />
```

as explained in [ngReact's documentation](https://github.com/davidchang/ngReact#the-reactdirective-service), there is no output at all.

Indeed is seems the DOM is not altered by **React's Virtual DOM**:

```
 <raisedbutton label="Primary" primary="{true}" class="ng-scope"></raisedbutton>
```

In the **.directive** definition I tried:

- console.log("load directives..."): if it's put in the JS file but **outside** of the .directive function call, it shows the output. if inside the .directive() no output on console.
- I tried to write "Raisedbutton" with and without ' '
- I tried to use app.directive, instead of defining a separate module: same result (by the way: what's the difference?)

Any clue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow angular rules when using directives. The directive name `raisedButton` should be used in markup as `<raised-button>`. (Change directive name from RaisedButton to raisedButton).

The directive attributes can only be strings, so using primary="{true}" like in React is probably not what you wanted.

Try this:
`<raised-button label="Primary" primary="true"></raised-button>`

Comment: thank you . I will try in few minutes. How do I verify if a directive has been correctly defined in Angular? (I have Angular Tools for Chrome) Also the "{true} is defined is adviced in ngReact's docs which is in fact an Angular module

Comment: I just tried. it simply doesn't work as there was no instante of the directive

Comment: Try to define a different directive with a simple Rect component. This will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: what do you mean? that directive is the simplest possible and it's written exactly as explained in the docs

Comment: Did you forget to inject ngReact as a dependency?
angular.module('myapp.reactDirectives', ['react'])

Comment: Yes, I am (it's "react", not "ngReact" according to the docs. how can I verify if the directive actually exists?

Comment: Can you post your code? Because your example shows angular.module('myapp.reactDirectives', []) which doesn't have the "react" injected.

Comment: actually I just understood your point. The module was injected in the main module/application but not in the module which defines the directives. I guess that's why it's being ignored by Angular. I decided to use a different technology stack to speed up the development but you may be right and therefore I will accept your answer for the effort put :)
would you just be so kind to clarify me the last question?( I tried to use app.directive, instead of defining a separate module: same result by the way: what's the difference?)